# What is the part name / description for these test points?

Tags: components, identification

What is the name/description for the test point pins on this board?[image: Test point pin array]
I've tried Digikey for all combination of binding post, test pins et, but no luck.

These are through hole parts, height ~6mm, pin dia 1mm.

Comment: There's a [whole category](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/test-and-measurement/test-points/2294346) for test points - did you not find them in there?

Comment: are those spring type or rigid. Measure the height and diameter and share pls

Comment: @Umar: Rigid, not spring loaded. I'll post the dimensions shortly, but the other answers have helped greatly.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I have found this one very similar to the test point. it will be impossible and not worth the time to search by only image as reference. This link gives a lot of similar looking parts you are looking for. Please feel free to [choose](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?pv30=1&pv30=179&FV=fff40016%2Cfff80310%2C1140050&k=pin&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=500)..

Answer (score 1):

In Digikey's hierarchy look for:

Product Index > Connectors, Interconnects > Terminals - PC Pin, Single Post Connectors

For example, this one (P/N [3137-1-00-21-00-00-08-0](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/3137-1-00-21-00-00-08-0/ED90541-ND/436861)):

[image]

There are many other types! Depends on the exact dimensions you need.

Answer (score 1):

Below testPoints may suits your requirement

1 [MULTICOMP  TEST-27  TEST PIN, PCB, 1.5MM](http://in.element14.com/multicomp/test-27/test-pin-pcb-1-5mm/dp/1702011)

[image]

2 [WEARNES CAMBION  460-2970-02-03-00..  TEST POINT, PCB](http://in.element14.com/wearnes-cambion/460-2970-02-03-00/test-point-pcb/dp/2061050)

[image]

3 [MULTICOMP  TEST-4  TEST PIN, PCB, 0.95MM](http://in.element14.com/multicomp/test-4/test-pin-pcb-0-95mm/dp/1702009)

[image]

4 [MULTICOMP  TEST-22  TEST PIN, PCB, 1.0MM](http://in.element14.com/multicomp/test-22/test-pin-pcb-1-0mm/dp/1702010)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Definitely those are test points. There are many kinds, not necessarily you will find the specific part on digikey.

Answer (score 0):

These are often referred to as turret connectors or turret lugs.